# Dynamic Bootstrap Grid PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to create a somewhat flexible dynamic bootstrap grid system.

For example,

if item_count = 3 and item_per_line = 2 the result should be **'row col-6 col-6 row col-12'**
if item_count = 3 and item_per_line = 3 the result should be **'row col-4 col-4 col-4'**
if item_count = 3 and item_per_line = 1 the result should be **'row col-12 row col-12 row col-12'**
if item_count = 5 and item_per_line = 3 the result should be **'row col-4 col-4 col-4 row col-6 col-6'**

I have this code that adds row every 2 item this code works but the column grid is not working:

```
$html = '';
$totalItemPerLine = 2;
$totalItem = 3;
                        
for($i = 0; $i < $totalItem; $i++){
    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == 0){
        $html .= '<div class="row">'; // OPEN ROW
    }
                        
    $html .= '<div class="col"> col '.$i.'</div>';
                        
    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == ($totalItemPerLine-1)){
        $html .= '</div>'; // CLOSE ROW
    }
}
                        
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $html = '';
$totalItem = 3;
$totalItemPerLine = 1;

$classes = array();
switch ($totalItemPerLine) {
    case 3:
        for ($i = 0; $i < $totalItemPerLine; $i++) $classes[$i] = "col-4";
        break;
    case 2:
        $classes[0] = "col-6";
        $classes[1] = "col-6";
        $classes[2] = "col-12";
        break;
    case 1:
        for ($i = 0; $i < $totalItemPerLine; $i++) $classes[$i] = "col-12";
        break;
}
$rows = ceil($totalItem / $totalItemPerLine);
for($i = 0; $i < $totalItem; $i++){

    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == 0){
        $html .= '<div classes="row">'; // OPEN ROW
    }
    $current_row = (int) ($i / $totalItemPerLine) + 1;
    echo ' now='.$current_row;
    $is_last_row = ($rows == $current_row);
    echo ' last='.$is_last_row;
    if ($is_last_row && $totalItem != $totalItemPerLine && ($totalItem - $totalItemPerLine) % 2 == 0 && $totalItemPerLine > 1)
        $class = "col-".(12 / ($totalItem - $totalItemPerLine));
    elseif ($totalItem - $i == 1 && $totalItem % $totalItemPerLine != 0)
        $class = "col-12";
    else
        $class = (isset($classes[$i % $totalItemPerLine])?$classes[$i % $totalItemPerLine]:'');     
    $html .= '<div classes="col '.$class.'"> col '.$i.'</div>';
                    
    if($i % $totalItemPerLine == ($totalItemPerLine-1)){
        $html .= '</div>'; // CLOSE ROW
    }
}
                    
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: there is an error when totalItem > 3 Undefined array key 3

Comment: @Blank317 it doesn't give me an error, but I changed the code

Comment: There is no error but it is not working now. it only takes effect on the first 3 columns the others are col-12. Example 6 total items then 3 items per row, the output is row col-4 col-4 col-4 row col-12 col-12

Comment: I edited the code, but it's not the right way to go, you can't handle exceptions with dozens of if's.
You have to use the flex display, which adjusts itself. Some if it takes the same, but you'll do it first.